# What does it mean when a Perl method returns a "hashref"?

Tags: perl

I'm trying to decrypt a Perl code which I'm not familiar with, somehow related to HashRef.
I'm using Amazon::S3, but my question is a general Perl question. See the code below:

```
use Amazon::S3;
my $s3 = Amazon::S3->new( ... );
my $response = $s3->buckets;
```

Documentation (here) sais, about s3->buckets:

```
Returns undef on error, else HASHREF of results
```

The following line is working for me, but I don't understand why:

```
for $b in ( @ { $response->{buckets} } ) {
    print "bucket: " . $b->bucket . "\n";
}
```

I'm Puzzled by each operator on the first line.

What type exactly are `$response`, `$respone->{bucket}`.
Looks like the expression within the `for` is an array, but I don't understand this syntax: `@{ ... }`?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Let's go through it piece-by-piece.

`$s3` is your S3 object. `$s3->buckets` calls the `buckets` method on that object, and we store the results in `$response`. As the docs say, the results are a hash reference; a reference is a scalar that points to another value. If you're familiar with pointers, the idea is the same.

If we had a plain hash `%response`, we could get at the `buckets` key in the hash by saying `$response{buckets}`. Since we have a hash *reference*, we have to use the dereference operator (`->`) to get at the key, so that becomes `$response->{buckets}`.

But we're not done yet. `$response->{buckets}` is *itself* a reference, in this case an array reference. Here we see another form of dereferencing. We could, if we wanted to get at just one item in the referenced array, say `$response->{buckets}[0]`, for example. But we want the whole list, so we use the `@` operator to dereference the entire array. Since our array reference is contained in a complex structure, we use curlies to contain the expression that has the reference. So `@{ $response->{buckets} }` gets us the array.

That's doing a whole lot in a single statement.

For more on references, which can be one of the trickiest subjects to learn in Perl, see the following:

- [perlreftut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) - Perl reference tutorial
- [perldsc](http://perldoc.perl.org/perldsc.html) - Perl data structures cookbook
- [perllol](http://perldoc.perl.org/perllol.html) - All about arrays of arrays
- [perlref](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlref.html) - The main Perl references documentation

Comment: perlreftut perlreftut perlreftut :)

Answer (score 4):

Welcome to the world of Perl references!  You're going to find the [reference tutorial](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) very handy.

The syntax `@{...}` takes a scalar value and tries to de-reference it into an array.  There's also `%{...}`, which tries to de-reference into a hash.  The curlies are optional, so you can also write `@$reference` or `%$reference` to get the same effect.  Some people find them visually useful when the reference is inside a hash or an array, as is the case here.

To help you understand the data structure a bit more, try using something like Data::Dumper.

```
use Data::Dumper;
print Dumper $response;
print Dumper $response->{buckets};
# The docs say that buckets is a hashref.  It also happens that
# you can coerce a hash into an array.  Let's treat it as a hash
# and see what's inside it, manually.  The Dumper call above should
# have already provided the structure to you, though.
foreach my $k (keys %{$response->{buckets}}) {
    print "$k => " . Dumper $response->{buckets}->{$k}
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can examine the type of a variable with the ref() function.

@{ ... } means "de-reference scalar ... as array". So if you go like this: my $aref=['a', 'b']; accessing @{$aref} will yield the array ('a', 'b').

Similarly %{ ... } for hash-references.

See perlreftut for more information.